# Images (PNG) don't show up in final exe of c++ Win32 project

Tags: c++, gdi+

To begin with, a small sample of my code:

```
// Includes and namespaces
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Forward declarations

static TCHAR szWindowClassIntro[] = _T("codbo2_trainer_intro");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Call of Duty Black Ops II Trainer");

HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcIntro(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

const int INTRO_WIDTH = 850;
const int INTRO_HEIGHT = 534;

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Following function is used to paint everything on intro window

void onPaintIntro(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);
    FontFamily fontFamily(L"Calibri");

    // Draw background image for intro
    Image introBg(L"Intro_border.png"); // IMAGE CAN BE FOUND HERE: http://i.imgur.com/H5Jc4Fj.jpg
    UINT introBgWidth = introBg.GetWidth();
    UINT introBgHeight = introBg.GetHeight();
    Rect introBgRect(0, 0, introBgWidth, introBgHeight);
    graphics.DrawImage(&introBg, introBgRect, 0, 0, introBgWidth, introBgHeight, UnitPixel);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Main function of trainer

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    hInst = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wcexIntro;
    wcexIntro.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcexIntro.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcexIntro.lpfnWndProc = WndProcIntro;
    wcexIntro.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcexIntro.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcexIntro.hInstance = hInst;
    wcexIntro.hIcon = NULL;
    wcexIntro.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcexIntro.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(5, 0, 0));
    wcexIntro.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcexIntro.lpszClassName = szWindowClassIntro;
    wcexIntro.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcexIntro))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Call of Duty Black Ops II Trainer"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    HWND hWndIntro = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClassIntro,
        szTitle,
        WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        INTRO_WIDTH, INTRO_HEIGHT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL
        );

    SetWindowLong(hWndIntro, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
    SetWindowLong(hWndIntro, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWndIntro, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWndIntro, RGB(5, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);

    if (!hWndIntro)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Call of Duty Black Ops II Trainer"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Show window
    ShowWindow(hWndIntro, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWndIntro);

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Callback function to process input on intro window

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcIntro(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);

    switch (message)
    {    
    // WM_PAINT
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        onPaintIntro(hdc);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've been making a trainer in c++ for Call of Duty (first c++ experience, sorry n00b), and finally finished today.
There is one small problem; **the images (PNG) in the final exe of my project don't show up.**

The images can be viewed here: http://imgur.com/6mWtETS,0ajBwE9,JlMVUYR,k8AIbAn#0

(The first two being the ones I get when debugging the trainer.

I think it has something to do with the how I'm using GDI+ to load the images, but I don't know exactly what because the trainer doesn't generate any error.

If anyone is wondering, I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: A small isolated self-contained example that reproduces the problem and can be copied, pasted and compiled would be very helpful to debug this.

Comment: Hope the sample is helpful, thanks for telling me.

Comment: Programs without error checking fail to get their job done in an undiagnosable way.  It is not optional, using assert() is a minimum requirement, fix your code.

Comment: The first step for mysterious problems like you describe is to write the shortest program that exhibits the problem behavior. Once you've done that, the fix is usually obvious. And if not, it'll be a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Well that's pretty much the sample I included above, I don't think it can get much shorter.

Comment: Is the image in the same directory as your executable? It seems to me you're loading it from a file

Comment: Marco A. Thanks, Damn I feel stupid now haha. That seemed to be the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to load the image from a file (cfr. [Image GDI+ object constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and that means the image has to be in the same directory where your application resides on a Windows platform.